# Saving data in Firebase in a numbered list

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save my data like this:

`- Parent
   - 1
      - Value here
      - Another value
   - 2
      - Value here
      - Another value`

And so on. Right now I am using this to add an item to the `Parent` array:

```
func save() {
  let ref = AppDatabaseReference.users(uid: uid).reference()
  ref.child("parent").childByAutoId().setValue(toDictionary())
}
item.save()
```

This works but it saves each item under a unique string (as expected). But it makes it more difficult to reference things for me.

`- Parent
   - dhsaifhafh86
      - Value here
      - Another value
   - dhsaifusfh53
      - Value here
      - Another value`

I thought about adding square brackets around `toDictionary()` like `ref.child("parent").setValue([toDictionary()])` but then it just replaces the existing children under parent rather than adding a new child:

`- Parent
    - Replaced stuff
    - You'll never win!`

If it helps, `toDictionary()` looks like this:

```
func toDictionary() -> [String: Any] {
   return [
      "title": title,
      "description": description,
      "stuff": stuff,
      "more stuff": moreStuff
    ]
}
```

Comment: why is it difficult to reference?

Comment: I want to loop through it and place the data in UICollectionViewCells which are numbered and it would make it easier. So far I've been looping through it and placing the data in an array which I then reference when plugging information in, but I'd prefer to do something like `ref.child("parent").child(indexPath.item).etc` rather than `myArray[indexPath.item]` as the Firebase info can change.

Answer (score 0):

i did something like this-

```
let ref=firebase().database().ref("Parent");
ref.once("value").then(snap=>{
  let length=snap.val()?Object.keys(snap.val()).length:0;
  ref.update({[length+1]:{Value here,Another value}});
});
```